# Redirect my domain name to specific port

Tags: linux, node.js, networking, dns, port

I currently have a website running under apache on my VPS, but i'm planning to run another website with NodeJS.

Since apache runs on port 80 and NodeJS on port 3000 i was wondering how i could manage that when someone type the domain name domain.com, it binds to the port 3000 ?

Also, is it possible that after the redirect on the browser it shows only http://domain.com and not http://domain.com:3000 ?

Comment: You can't "hide" the port that way, unless you have something proxying that traffic in Apache.

Answer (score 1):

Use ProxyPass:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / http://domain.com:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://domain.com:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it. Btw, if my website needs socket.io on port 4000, if i use connect(http://domain.com:4000) will that bind to port 4000 or 3000 ?